# XPATH Expression to determine the receiver in SAP PI

Tags: xml, xpath, sap-pi, sap-xi

I have a requirement where i need to determine the receiver based on condition in SAP PI XPATH expression. Can someone help please.

- condition 2:

  `<bizTransactionList><bizTransaction type>` contains the value "**urn:epcglobal:cbv:btt:resadv**” , this is also true but need to validate two more conditions as mentioned below in "Excep't

except :
- when the last segment of the value contains the string “.008” in `<Biztransaction>` and that the `<bizStep>` contains the word “commissioning “ 
- or

when the last segment of the value contains the string “.008” in `<Biztransaction>` and that the `<bizStep>` contains the word “receiving “

Comment: So both your samples inputs are NOT supposed to be selected? If so, can you post one that should?

Comment: Your attempted "XPath" uses an undefined namespace prefix and is not even close to even being syntactically correct.  Your "requirements" are a jumbled mess.    Read [ask].

Comment: sorry, i have update the conditions again & provided two valid sample xmls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the following XPath should work :

```
//bizTransaction[@type="urn:epcglobal:cbv:btt:prodorder"]|//bizTransaction[@type="urn:epcglobal:cbv:btt:resadv"][contains(.,".008")][preceding::bizStep[1][not(contains(text(),"commissioning") or contains(text(),"receiving"))]]
```

Output : 2 nodes

We use `|` operator to "join" 2 expressions. The first part will select "bizTransaction" element regarding 1 condition ("urn:epcglobal:cbv:btt:prodorder"). The second part will select "bizTransaction" element regarding 3 conditions : "urn:epcglobal:cbv:btt:resadv", ".008" and with "bizStep" element which not contains 2 specific keywords ("commissioning" or "receiving").

Comment: Thank you verymuch,  i need to use this in SAP PI system, we have limited option there. so i edited your logic according to that.. .008 condition is working but contains text logic i am missing something.

Comment: OK. My knowledge of SAP is limited to "Business Object"... PI uses probably a subset of XPath 1.0. You can replace the part "text()" with `[not(contains(.,"commissioning") or contains(.,"receiving"))]`. Please provide the error log if necessary. And your current XPath expression (even if it fails in some parts).

Comment: I updated new XPATH expression i tried in my question above.. somehow it is not working as expcted. in the some of the TRUE cases it is not idenfiying the receiver.. Please check once.

Comment: Finding the right syntax is not easy. After reading some examples, this is what I would have tried : `(/EPCISDocument/EPCISBody/EventList/AggregationEvent/bizTransactionList/bizTransaction[(@name = 'urn:epcglobal:cbv:btt:prodorder')] OR /EPCISDocument/EPCISBody/EventList/AggregationEvent/bizTransactionList/bizTransaction[(@type = 'urn:epcglobal:cbv:btt:recadv') and contains(.,'.008') and /EPCISDocument/EPCISBody/EventList/AggregationEvent/bizStep[not(contains(.,'commissioning') or contains(.,'receiving') or contains(.,'shipping'))]] EX)`

Comment: Coloured for better reading : https://framapic.org/Wn44qIrZo04V/FKpNREVBBzT1.PNG